# MX record imported in Route53 from Godaddy with bad format

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, amazon-route53

As per the title, I am importing the zone files from Godaddy to Route53 and I noticed a weird thing. I don't know if is the right format for Route53, but the MX records in Godaddy looks like that

[image]

When I import this record in Route53 I can see that in the MX record, at the **Value** column

```
10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.websitename.com.
```

Of course if I do a nslookup on that address it say that doens't exists.

```
 nslookup mailstore1.secureserver.net.websitename.com
 Server:        127.0.1.1
 Address:   127.0.1.1#53
** server can't find mailstore1.secureserver.net.websitename.com: NXDOMAIN
```

My question is, this is a normal behaviour for Route53 or I need to manually remove the website name, from the address in the Value column for the MX record?

Comment: Yes, remove the trailing noise.  How did you "import" these records? What tool or service?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enter the value into Route53 with a dot on the end so that it doesn't append your domain to it.

```
mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

Comment: I'd +1 if this also had an explanation: something short about FQDN.

Comment: Yes, but no.  Route 53 doesn't do the same thing as BIND and assume records without a trailing dot need to be qualified.  This is a problem with whatever tool was used for the "import."